# Can I move my downloaded games from PS3 to PS4?

Tags: ps3, ps4

We have a large collection of downloaded games from the store, mainly PSX gen (Crash Bandicoot, Spyro, FF7 etc.) and I was wondering if we can move them/re-download them onto the PS4?

Comment: Not sure if the [game-saves] tag belongs on here...

Comment: just to download and store or play them, if the latter I don't think so as i'm pretty sure the PS4 has no backwards compatibility though i may be mistaking it for no PS3 backwards compatibility

Comment: @Memor-X Play them. On the PS3 I downloaded them from the store and we were able to play them, and (from what I remember of the early console war) PS4 seemed far more versatile.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178987/considering-a-ps4-are-all-games-that-have-a-download-now-able-to-be-download Not a duplicate, but I think my answer there partly answers your question too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to play any of them. PS4 doesn't support ps, ps2 or ps3 games. You can't re download them onto the console from the store for that reason. It is reasonable to assume that if Sony ever add support for, say, downloaded PS1 games then previously purchased titles will be available to you in the store.

You can't use a USB stick or similar to transfer them either as far as I'm aware, though since there's no point in doing so I haven't tried.

Comment: Well poo. Was hoping to trade them out, but it looks like we'll have to switch back and forth any time we want to use a different console (we currently have 3 different consoles already plugged in).

Answer (score 3):

You can't move them over.

It currently looks like the [PlayStation Now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Now) system will be the only way to play PS1, PS2, and PS3 games on the PS4.

Having said that, the PlayStation TV and PS Vita can play PSX titles from PSN.

Answer (score 2):

Okay: I looked and looked as I am a ps3 owner I really want a ps4 but I just got the new game Call of Duty  Advanced Warfare. I didn't want to buy a ps4 without knowing if I could redownload my game (s) to the ps4 the answer is yes you can but only if its from the psn store and if it says "Cross-buy" so if you have a ps3 and want to buy a ps4 yes you can download your previous digital copys from the psn to your new system.

Comment: I'll have to look into this. It may be a new feature because (as you can see) there have been a few before that have said no. Do you know if this works with previous gen titles as well? Eg. PS One titles like Crash Bandicoot and Spyro?

Comment: Looking at the Playstation Store (in USA) there are no titles with the tags `PS One Classics` or `PS2 Classics` that are available for the `PS4`

Comment: I couldn't find any actual games tagged with `PS3 | PS4`, only documentation.  But I didn't browse all the thousands of titles.