# Can I move my downloaded games from my Xbox 360 to Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one

I asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184437/can-i-move-my-downloaded-games-from-ps3-to-ps4) earlier and I was wondering if the case was the same for Xbox?

To summarize: I have a series of arcade games and downloaded games that were purchased from the store on my Xbox 360, and I was wondering if I could transfer them over to the Xbox One?

Comment: The One is about to add backwards compatibility. Please do check if your arcade games are featured to be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xbox One can't play Xbox 360 games at all due to using a different system architecture.

Both Microsoft and Sony made conscious decisions to not try to support the previous generation via emulation this time around.

Edit:  Electronic Arts has a service named [EA Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EA_Access) that can be used to play certain EA titles on the Xbox One including some older titles.  It requires a monthly subscription fee, though.

Edit 2: This answer is very out of date. See [TZHX's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257154/87105) for the current state of things.

Comment: Although I said stuff about not supporting via emulation, Sony still plans to support select PS1, PS2, and PS3 titles over the PlayStation Now service.  However, it looks like you'll have to buy them again and/or pay money for said service.  It's unclear if the Xbox One will have a similar service or not.

Comment: Please consider updating your answer, The Xbox One will soon feature backwards compatibility and will likely do so for quite a large number of digital (arcade) titles.

Comment: @Eric Updating my answer before the feature comes out would be about unreleased content, which is a close reason for questions... so it's generally a bad idea to put it in answers as well.

Comment: The feature is in beta and available to preview members. I am not saying you should state it exists but you can give readers the outlook and sources. As it is now, your second sentence contradicts what Microsoft recently announced. Inaccurate information is, for me, a down-vote reason.

Comment: I haven't really looked into it, but recently I've seen a number of advertisements in my One dashboard mentioning playing 360 games on the One.

Comment: @DCShannon Things have changed since this answer.  TZHX's answer tells you what the current state of things are.

Comment: @Powerlord Yeah, they posted that after I left my comment. Upvoted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is [a list](http://majornelson.com/blog/xbox-one-backward-compatibility/) of about 80 games for the Xbox 360 that can be played on the Xbox One through a form of backwards compatibility. More games are being added to this list on a semi-regular basis -- often as part of a pre-order bonus of some sort. For example, the entire Gears of War series was made backwards-compatible upon the release of the remastered version.

This works best for titles you own digital copies of, and going forward most games for `360 offered in the "Games with Gold" program should be backwards compatible (according to Microsoft), so you'll gradually build up a library of titles if you remember to claim them on either your `360 console or the web.

Titles you own digitally that are eligible should appear in the "Ready to Install" portion of the "My Games and Apps" app when signed into the same Xbox Live account.

The backwards compatibility also works for disc-based games if you have any that are on the list, but the disc simply acts as a licence for the content -- you'll need to download the emulated version from Xbox Live before you can play it.

Because the compatibility is done through software emulation, rather than the console natively being backwards compatible (as was the case with the PS1->PS2 compatibility) there are occasionally minor performance issues in the emulated version that don't exist in the original game. These are in my experience fairly rare though.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Xbox One has a completely different game library, the games will not transfer over.

That being said, there are a handful of games that will transfer saves and DLC over if you purchase the upgraded version. Minecraft and Pinball FX 2 are the ones that immediately that come to mind that offer such feature.

Comment: Also many of the newest AAA games are allowing or did allow transfers from 360 to Xbox One (and ps3 to ps4) of saves in some cases, largely for pvp levels in FPS games.